# MATLAB: How to access a matrix loaded from a .mat file from a function?

Tags: matlab, function, load, mat-file

I have three `.mat` files, `m1.mat`, `m2.mat` and `m3.mat`, each representing a cell array `m1`, `m2` and `m3` respectively. I need to access the cell arrays programatically from within a function. Inside the function I declare an array of strings to store the filenames. I loop through the filenames and within each loop load the file and *try to* find dimensions of the cell array in the file.

The question is: how do I *access* the cell array? If I say `x = load ('m1.mat')` it does not return a matrix, it just says

```
m1: {10x2 cell}
size(m1) % return 1 1
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using dynamic feild names

```
for nm = {'m1', 'm2', 'm3' }
    ld = load( [nm{1},'.mat'] );
    ca = ld.(nm{1}); % ca should hold the cell array loaded from the file
    size( ca )
end
```